# linkedin bot using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains, ScrollOrigin
import os
import time

URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3483760254&keywords=python%20developer&refresh=true"
EMAIL = os.environ.get("MYEMAIL")
PASSWORD = os.environ.get("MYPASSWORD")

# Setup the chrome driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
service = Service("/home/hoods/Documents/development/chromedriver")
chrome_driver_path = "/home/hoods/Documents/development/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get(URL)
# maximize window to avoid element finding issues
driver.maximize_window()
print(EMAIL)
print(PASSWORD)

# Sign in with driver, sleep for page to load
sign_in = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/a[1]")
time.sleep(3)
sign_in.click()
time.sleep(3)

username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]')
username.send_keys(EMAIL)
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
login_form_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".login__form button")
login_form_button.click()

# Minimize the chat window
time.sleep(2.5)
minimize_message = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="msg-overlay"]/div[1]/header/div[2]')
minimize_message.click()

# Select easy apply filter so i can apply with only my phone number
time.sleep(2.5)
easy_apply_filter = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-reusables__filters-bar"]/ul/li[8]/div')
easy_apply_filter.click()

# click a job from easy apply list
time.sleep(2)
jobs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".job-card-container--clickable")
time.sleep(2)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
'''
this was my earlier portion to apply to jobs, i abandoned it and went for the other assignment task because I'm not 
ready to apply for jobs yet and i think linkedin was flagging my bot when i hit apply

#apply to the 2nd or 3rd job
time.sleep(2.5)
apply_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "jobs-apply-button--top-card")
apply_button.click()
time.sleep(2.5)
phone_number_entry = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".artdeco-text-input .artdeco-text-input--input")
phone_number_entry.send_keys("4173103621")
phone_number_entry.submit()
'''

# try:
#     jobs[1].click()
# except:
#     jobs[2].click()
for job in jobs:
    try:
        if job == jobs[0]:
            pass
        else:
            job.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            save_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jobs-save-button.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--3.artdeco-button--secondary")
            time.sleep(2)
            save_button.click()
            follow_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".follow.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--secondary.ml5")
            time.sleep(2)
            follow_button.click()
            time.sleep(2)


    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

This code is supposed to save the listing and then follow each company from the search results 'python developer' and it does that.
The problem is that when i create the list of job elements i think it only adds the ones currently visible to on the webpage.  When i add print(len(jobs)) the output is 7. So there are 7 items in the list.

I would like help with how to scroll down and get the rest. I've looked over the selenium documentation for hours but nothing seems to work and it doesn't actually tell you how to implement the scroll. I either need to get the rest of the jobs onto the list, or scroll down one by one and click them all, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(0, 1500);", main_box)
```

where main_box is the element you want to scroll into. You need to call this whenever you want to do a scroll down. For example you could either scroll down several times before fetching jobs or scroll down every time you finish iterating a for loop (maybe add a guard to check for duplicates and ensure that there are new jobs found).